# Average of 2 functions

Tags: c++, function, average

When I run this code I seem to keep getting off averages and was wondering if anybody has any suggestion's one example is tried is just doing 5 employees that all missed 5 days and keep getting a average of 15, am I doing the math wrong? thanks again for the help. I posted the full code just in case it is not the function I tried to make it as neat as possible so sorry if its a little messy been programing for less than a month.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

function prototypes

//return type: void
//parameter type: 1 int by refrence
//purpose: This function asks the user for the number of employees in the company.
void GetNumEmployees(int&);

//return type: int
//parameter type: 1 int
//Purpose: The function should as the user to enter the number of days each employee missed during the past year
int TotalDaysMissed(int);

//return type: float
//parameters: 2 int
//Purpose: Returns the average of total number of days missed for all employees in the company during the year
float AverageDaysMissed(int, int);

int main()
{
    //Declare and Initilize Variables
    int empnum = 0, daysmissed = 0 ;
    float averagedays = 0.0 ;
    GetNumEmployees(empnum) ;
    daysmissed = TotalDaysMissed(empnum)    ;
    averagedays = AverageDaysMissed(empnum, daysmissed) ;
    cout<<"The Average Work Days your Employees Missed is "<<averagedays<<endl ;
    return 0;
}
//function definitions
void GetNumEmployees(int &emp)
{
    do
    {
        cout<<"Enter the number of Employees in the company: ";
        cin>>emp ;
        if(emp < 1)
            cout<<"Invalid. Cannot be Less than 1\n\n";
    }
    while (emp < 1) ;
}

int TotalDaysMissed(int empn)
{
    int daysmissed = 0 ;
    int total = 0 ;
    for(int n = empn; n > 0  ; n--)
    {
        do
        {
            cout<<"How Many days did Employee "<<n<< " miss? " ;
            cin>>daysmissed ;
            total += daysmissed;
            if(daysmissed < 0)
                cout<<"Invalid days must be a Positive Number\n\n";
        }
        while(daysmissed < 0) ;
    }
    return total;
}

float AverageDaysMissed(int empn, int daystotal)
{
    float average = 0.0     ;
    average = (empn + daystotal) / 2.0 ;
    return average;
}
```

Comment: `average = (empn + daystotal) / 2.0` - this is not how average is calculated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating average incorrectly.

You have 5 employees who all missed 5 days each.

(5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5) / 5 = 5

Your average is 5.

So if you have 5 employees who missed days in this sequence: 4, 3, 2, 4, 5.
Then your average = (4 + 3 + 2 + 4 +5) / 5 = 3.6

Average is the sum of all observations divided by the number of observations.